# Search engine to provide xml file with results

Tags: java, xml, search-engine

i would like to know if there's any chance to get the results of a search engine in xml format - to be used in Java, parsing , for instance.
I know Google does not provide that but you can work on it a little more difficult. Is something else more available? (from among the other search engines)
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Bing (Microsoft Web Search Engine) does provide an [XML API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250893.aspx)

Comment: thank you but their link doesn't work; i tried http://api.bing.net/xml.aspx?AppId=62C64099FE23C551A600AA929EF4B3C7790E2CBA&Version=2.2&Market=en-US&Query=testign&Sources=web+spell&Web.Count=1    not working

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't wor ? I get an xml result when clicking on your link

Answer (score 0):

Google **[CustomSearch API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)** provides both JSON and **Atom** (which is XML itself) interfaces. Moreover, there are ready-to-use **libraries** (e.g. [this one](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#CustomSearch_API)) for the API.